# How to use Apache with Windows DNS Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, hosting, website, apache-2.4

I have recently bought a domain, and I have set up Windows DNS Server on my Server 2008 R2 machine to handle the DNS. To obtain the info you might need use this:
http://www.intodns.com/gamersvision.co.uk

I am now trying to get Apache to serve the HTTP requests for the domain, but I really don't know where to start?

What I HAVE changed already (in httpd.conf):
Listen 193.200.158.136:80
ServerName www.gamersvision.co.uk:80

I haven't touched anything else...oh, and environment info:
Full ownership of domain gamersvision.co.uk (registered with NameCheap.com).
Windows DNS Server (Fully configured I believe).
Windows Server 2008 R2.
Apache 2.4.x + PHP 5.3.14 + MySQL (Not that this really means much?).

I previously used IIS7, and had it working after a lot of trial and error but I now want to use Apache due to it's expandability (and support for .htaccess amongst other things).

Comment: Looked into it further, and my DNS Server is definitely configured correctly, it simply seems that Apache doesn't recognise it needs to accept connections to my domain name, however it does accept connections through the IP Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I played around with the config file, and it seemed a bit weird that I had a port number on the 'ServerName' config line, so I remove the port and www. (I CNAME'd www. to the domain in my DNS server) and voila!
ServerName gamersvision.co.uk